# is it possible to lock oracle 10g database table with ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, ado.net, oracle10g

I have a table that contains a maximum value that needs to be get and set by multiple programs. How can I lock the table for a while when old value is got and new is updated in C#? In  other words:

```
string sql = "lock table MaxValueTable in exclusive mode";  
using (DbCommand cmd = cnctn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    // execute command somehow!!
}

maxValue = GetMaxValue();
SetMaxValue(maxValue + X);

sql = "lock table MaxValueTable in share mode";  
using (DbCommand cmd = cnctn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    // execute command somehow!!
}
```

Comment: Cant' you use an Oracle Sequence instead? It would handle synchronization for you.

Comment: @Peter Lang. Perfect. A sequence is what he needs. Perhaps Matti can explain why he does otherwise.

Comment: @Matti- Peter's advice is sound- have a look at http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

Comment: Added my comment + some more information as answer :)

Comment: thanks! i do not know what sequence is. i would like to maintain generality (yes I know that this lock thing is just for oracle but elsewhere it's general) by using DbConnection-class. If this sequence thing is sound I can change to using OracleConnection class. have 2 check the link!

Answer (score 2):

Oracle can handle [locking](http://broadh2o.net/docs/database/oracle/oracleLocks.html) itself. Try to use Database features as far as possible.

[Sequence](http://www.psoug.org/reference/sequences.html) is the preferred way in Oracle as comments above will tell you.

Comment: You just can't lock it if you need to create the row the first time. You can't lock what's not there. Then you need the table lock.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a good practice to use providers for a specified database. Oracle has a dedicated provider for Microsoft.Net on his site, I would recommend using it. Note that all dedicated providers implement the same base classess so certain level of abstraction is kept. Secondly U definately need a transaction. I'd recommend doing that by invoking a stored procedure (either by executeNonQuery() or executeScalar() methods - depending on the result U need.

If You can't use stored procedures (U can't create them) then You have to use transations offered by the provider. Both Ole provider and ORacle provider offer transaction

```
using (Transaction t = cnctn.BeginTransation())


`//set some options like timeout, use serialization level like //Serializable in .Net TransactionScope


   {
        string sql = "lock table MaxValueTable in exclusive mode";
        using (DbCommand cmd = cnctn.CreateCommand())
        { 
           cmd.CommandText = sql;
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          // execute command somehow!! 
        } 
       maxValue = GetMaxValue();
       SetMaxValue(maxValue + X);
       //I presume U need to update the value in the table so some Update would be nice
       sql = "lock table MaxValueTable in share mode";
       using (DbCommand cmd = cnctn.CreateCommand())
       { 
           cmd.CommandText = sql;
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           // execute command somehow!! 
       }
       cnctn.Commit();
  }
  catch(SQLException e)
  {
     //log whatever, gracefully handle things
     t.Rollback();
     //throw;?
  }
  finally
  {
        cntn.close();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I try this later. You're the first one that really tried to answer my question!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should be using an [Oracle Sequence](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) instead - as already mentioned in my comment :)

It will return unique numbers whenever calling `NEXTVAL`.

---

If for some reason you cant' use a sequence, just perform an `UPDATE` on that row. Oracle will lock that row until you end your transaction (`COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`) and all other updates will wait until the lock is released.

---

**EDIT**:

If transactions are not supported in `ADO`, you could also put that into an Oracle Procedure using an [`AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems002.htm):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE allocate_sequence_numbers(
  in_size IN max_value_table.val%TYPE,
  out_next_sequence_number OUT max_value_table.val%TYPE
)
AS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  next_sequence_number max_value_table.val%TYPE;
BEGIN
  UPDATE max_value_table
  SET val = val + in_size
  RETURNING val - in_size
  INTO out_next_sequence_number;
  COMMIT;
END allocate_sequence_numbers;
```

It will update your table to "allocate" the specified number of values, and return the first number of the sequence you allocated. The next application that calls it will receive the next sequence number.

The `UPDATE` causes a lock on that row, so other calls have to wait for that lock to be released. By using `COMMIT` inside the `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`, the lock is released, while your own transaction will not be affected.

Comment: +1. This is definitely the best approach, providing the unique ID fits into what a sequence offers.

Comment: sorry. i cannot use it for various reasons: 1. the database and table is existing one and i cannot alter it. 2. i might need a variable range or values from the table. i.e. I read value 65300 and write 65345 when i need 46 (was it right?) values. with sequence the interval is fixed.

Comment: what do you mean by "just perform an UPDATE on that row" in DAO.NET commands are not necessarily part of transaction (i think). so do you mean that i create a transaction then select command and give the tranaction to command as it's transaction then execute it then same with update and execute and commit. and oracle locks the table when select begins and unlocks it when commit is executed.

Comment: thanks for your effort. transactions are definitely supported in ADO.NET! I said that "commands are not necessarily part of transaction (i think).". which means that you have to excplicitly create a txn and assign txn to a command. I have to check your answer later. i think there is more simple and more elegant way to do this... none of the answers are really to my original question.

Comment: I think the second part of my answer should be quite elegant. Update the row, and then select it. The row will be locked for other transactions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lock table command

```
LOCK TABLE [schema.] table IN lockmode EXCLUSIVE [NOWAIT]
```

Note: you can't reset a lock until you end the transaction. So if you locked the table, you can't unlock it.

Comment: say what? as u can see from my QUESTION I know oracle has lock command... it's in sql variable int the code sample. what do you mean i cannot reset the lock? which transaction? i just lock it again in share mode.

Comment: No, if you lock it in share mode, the exclusive lock will be there for the rest of the transaction. You need transaction here. Locking and transaction isolation just doesn't work without transactions.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the lock after the statement that takes it you need a transaction.

Answer (score -1):

You can try another method. First enable table locking on the table. Say my table is `T`. Then

```
SQL> alter table t enable table lock   
2    /
```

Now, you can select, and any other select will wait, because you have a lock.

```
SQL> select *
  2  from t
  3  for update
  4  /
```

So, any select command else where in another session will not return and wait for the lock to be released. Remember, you need to do `COMMIT` to release the lock.

Comment: Row-level locking is a default feature and doesn't require use of "alter table ... enable table lock".

Comment: That's right. The query was there for in-case the table lock is disabled.